# How to create query string for SNS from API Gateway websocket integration

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway, query-string, amazon-sns

I have a REST API Gateway -> SNS integration working, but want to use with Websocket.  I can't figure out how to get any parameters except ?Action=Publish into the query string using the console.  The Request Template would seem to be the ticket, but whatever I put in there just gets written to the POST body, or ignored.  I think the variables I need to set are like integration.request.querystring.TopicArn.  Anyone know how to do that via console?  Or, if impossible in console, what is the quickest alternative to learn?